# Unable to create table missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it. The only error message I got is "missing right parenthesis". Please help

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
emp_no NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
emp_salary DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
djob VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES depot(djob)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `FOREIGN KEY`.  You can simply do:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_no NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    emp_salary DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    djob VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL REFERENCES depot(djob)
);
```

For the in-line declaration, `FOREIGN KEY` is not necessary.

Note that I also changed `VARCHAR()` to `VARCHAR2()`, which is more accepted for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

should't the last line be with foreign key as separate line?

`

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_no NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    emp_salary DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    djob VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES depot(djob)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19250

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
deptno number PRIMARY KEY,
dname varchar2(100));

CREATE TABLE employee (
emp_no NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
emp_salary DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
djob number NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_job FOREIGN KEY (djob) REFERENCES dept(deptno)
);
```